# Geocoding results with JS function - address split

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem with geocoder function.
This is my JS function:

```js
function init_map() {
            searchLanLon();
            var latitudine = document.getElementById('lat').value;
            var longitudine = document.getElementById('lng').value;

            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudine, longitudine);

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'location': myLatLng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var options = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: myLatLng,
                        mapeTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatLng, map: map, draggable: true });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
                        document.getElementById('address').value = results[0].formatted_address;

                    });
                    document.getElementById('address').value = results[0].formatted_address;

                } else {
                    alert("Problema nella ricerca : " + status);
                }
            });

        }
        window.onload = init_map;
```

The function works, but I need an address divided into street, number, city , postal- code for saved it in a database with this fields.

How can I split the address?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the geocoding docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses

You are using `formatted_address` but you have a lot more info for each result in `address_components`

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0829009197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0855988802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```